# How to get same track/song from Spotify on Apple Music and vice versa?

Tags: spotify, apple-musickit

I'm building a simple app, where users can share the song they're listening with friends. If the user is a Spotify subscriber and his/her friend is an Apple Music subscriber, and the Spotify user is sharing the song,
how can I search for the same song in apple catalog? Is there any common ID, like ISRC on Apple Music? Or any other comparison method?
I know how to use search already for songs/albums etc. The question is how to make sure that the result is the same song from spotify. Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: curious @guios how did this app go, was it a success? I’m looking at something similar atm

Answer (score 6):

The ISRC code is certainly the trick here. Here's how to search in either direction:

**Spotify to Apple Music**

```
curl -g -X "GET" "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/songs?filter[isrc]=ISRC" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer DEVELOPER_TOKEN"
```

**Apple Music to Spotify**

```
curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=isrc:ISRC&type=track" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH_TOKEN"
```

I wrote more about this on my [Medium](https://medium.com/@leemartin/how-to-match-tracks-between-spotify-and-apple-music-2d6b6159957e). Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Song model for MusicKit does not have ISRC according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/Song.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625-CH35-SW1). iTunes [EPF](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed/) has ISRC info, but this is not a part of MusicKit API.

Comment: Thanks you Bahri.

Comment: ISRC is available in the responses of Apple Music APIs now - but yes, you are correct that it is not in the documentation yet.

Comment: Thank you Ted. I've just checked and ISRC is in the response as you say. Unfortunately when I tried to search with the ISRC as search term, it is still giving me no results.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar with one of my projects, so hopefully it can get you on the right track. In short, you can use the iTunes API alongside the Spotify API to search for the same results.

An example in Python.

**Get the current playing song/artist with the Spotify API. Search through the response for the information you want, in my case, it was the artist name and album name.**

```
results = sp.currently_playing()
artist = results["item"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"]
album = results["item"]["album"]["name"]
```

**Look it up with the iTunes API.**

```
i_artist = itunes.search_album(album, artist)[0]
```

You'll have to learn how the API's work. With iTunes, a search results in a list of results. I'm taking my chances and just grabbing the first one (the most popular). But you can certainly filter through them to make sure it matches what you want. You'll obviously run into things like artists having the same album titles, or even sharing the same name.

It looks like your target platform is iOS, but my code should be a starting point. It's just a matter of saving the information from one platform into variables, and the searching then next one with them.

Hopefully I understood your question correctly, I can expand or provide more code if needed.

Comment: Thank you 23k. I've been doing like you said. But most of the calls returns different songs...even when comparing name, album and duration. But probably is the easiest way out, Or try EPF as @bahriOkuroglu says below. The ideal world would be an id as ISRC.

Comment: @GuilhermeSolDuschenes Yup that would be the most ideal solution. I also run into the problem of incorrect results more than I would like. I guess it's also dependent on how popular the song you are listening to is. I'll keep looking into this problem and update my answer if I find anything more reliable.

Comment: @23k, Thanks for your solution. Can you Please provide me a `search API` with the `parameters`?

Comment: @ilesh Not sure I understand what you're asking for.

Comment: @23k, iTunes Search API for the find the similar song of the Spotify. Are you using `isrc` or `songName`, `artist Name` and etc?